# Index TRUE occurrences preserving NA in a new vector

Tags: r, radix

I have what some of you might categorise as a dumb question, but I cannot solve it. I have this vector:

```
a <- c(NA,NA,TRUE,NA,TRUE,NA,TRUE)
```

And I want to get this in a new vector:

```
b <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,2,NA,3)
```

That simple. All the ways I am trying do not preserve the NA and I need them untouched. I would prefer if there would be a way in base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, use `cumsum()` while excluding the `NA` values:

```
a <- c(NA,NA,TRUE,NA,TRUE,NA,TRUE)

a[!is.na(a)] <- cumsum(a[!is.na(a)])
```

Output:

```
[1] NA NA  1 NA  2 NA  3
```

Comment: Brilliant! That serves me perfectly well. Let me take advantage of you a little more though :) What if from ```a <- c(NA,NA,TRUE,NA,FALSE,NA,TRUE)``` I would want to get  ```b <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,2)```? Thank you!!

Comment: why do you need 2 steps? Your answer works the way it is  right now. No need of two steps. Just upvoted

Comment: `a[!is.na(a)] <- cumsum(a[!is.na(a)])` works whether there are FALSE and TRUE or just TRUE values. You do not need `&` anywhere

Comment: Whoops you're correct, I initially tried something with a different approach. @Unai Vicente, as the great onyambu mentioned this will work as is.

Answer (score 2):

Using `replace` from `base R`

```
b <- replace(a, !is.na(a), seq_len(sum(a, na.rm = TRUE)))
b
[1] NA NA  1 NA  2 NA  3
```

---

Or slightly more compact option (if the values are logical/numeric)

```
cumsum(!is.na(a)) * a
[1] NA NA  1 NA  2 NA  3
```

#### Update

If the OP's vector is

```
a <- c(NA,NA,TRUE,NA,FALSE,NA,TRUE)
 (a|!a) * cumsum(replace(a, is.na(a), 0))
[1] NA NA  1 NA  1 NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace`ing the non-`NA`s with the `cumsum`.

```
replace(a, !is.na(a), cumsum(na.omit(a)))
# [1] NA NA  1 NA  2 NA  3
```